# Simulate the semantics of x86 opcode 'bsf' in Z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I am working on some assembly program analysis task using `Z3`. And I am trapped in simulating the semantics of `x86` opcode `bsf`.

The semantics of `bsf operand1 operand2` is defined as **searches the source operand (operand1) for the least significant set bit (1 bit).**

Its semantics can be simulated in `C` as:

```
if(operand1 == 0) {
  ZF = 0;
  operand2 = Undefined;
}
else {
  ZF = 0;
  Temporary = 0;
  while(Bit(operand1, Temporary) == 0) {
    Temporary = Temporary + 1;
    operand2 = Temporary;
  }
}
```

Right now, suppose each operand (e.g., register) maintains a `symbolic expression`, I am trying to simulate the above semantics in `Z3Py`. The code I wrote is something like this (simplified):

```
def aux_bsf(x):     # x is operand1
    if simplify(x == 0):
         raise Exception("undefined in aux_bsf")
    else:
         n = x.size()
         for i in range(n):
            b = Extract(i, i, x)
            if simplify(b == 1):
            return BitVecVal(i, 32)

    raise Exception("undefined in bsf")
```

However, I find that the evaluation of `simplify(x==0)` (e.g., `x` equals `BitVecVal(13, 32) + BitVec("symbol1", 32)`,) is always equal to `True`. In other words, **I am always trapped in the first exception**!

Am I doing anything wrong here..?

====================================================
OK, so I think what I need is something like:

```
def aux_bsf(x):
    def aux(x, i):
        if i == 31:
            return 31
        else:
            return If(Extract(i, i, x) == 1, i, aux(x, i+1))
    return aux(x, 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

simplify(x == 0) returns an *expression*, it does not return True/False, where False = 0. Python would treat an expression reference as a non-zero value and therefore take the first branch. Unless 'x' is a bit-vector constant, simplification would not return a definite value. The same issue is with simplify(b == 1).

You could encode such functions as a *relation* between operand1 and operand2, e.g., something along the lines of:

```
def aux_bsf(s, x, y):
    for k in range(x.size()):
        s.Add(Implies(lsb(k, x), y == k)

def lsb(k, x):
    first0 = True
    if k > 0:
       first0 = Extract(x, k-1,0) == 0
    return And(Extract(x,k,k) == 1, first0)
```

You can also use uninterpreted functions for the cases where aux_bsf is under-specified.

For example:

```
def aux_bsf(x):
    bv = x.sort()
    bsf_undef = Function('bsf-undef', bv, bv)
    result = bsf_undef(x)
    for k in reverse(range(bv.size()))
        result = If(Extract(x, k, k) == 1), BitVecVal(k, bv), result)
    return result

def reverse(xs):
    ....
```